# Does the Slavic word rā́dъ have cognates in Indo-iranian?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, slavic-languages

I found a source which gives the PIE origin: http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P1589.html
But it only lists Slavic reflexes. Are there related words in Persian or Sanskrit?

Wikipedia claims the name of the Indian goddess Radha is related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radha#Etymology, but gives no source for this claim.

Comment: Without citation and improbable:  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AF#Persian  (For others wishing to dig deeper.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As so often, Wikipedia is completely wrong about this. The Sanskrit name Rādhā cannot possibly be related to Persian rād “generous”. Indo-Iranian post-vocalic dh becomes y in Persian, not d.

Comment: Got it, thanks. But can the Persian rād be related to Slavic radъ?

Comment: No, for the same reason. Slavic -d cannot correspond to Persian -d after vowels.

Answer (score 3):

The etymology of Slavic root is also unclear. Vasmer writes that Greek sources give the following versions of the names of Slavic princes: ᾽Αρδάγαστος, ᾽Αρδαμέρι, which are evidently the versions of Slavic names Radogostь "happy with guests" and Radoměrь respectively.

This hints the root had something before the r-. Some link it to Greek root ἔρως "love" which in turn also has obscure etymology.

If this theory wrong, then possible cognates (according to Vasmer) are Anglo-Saxon rǿtu "joy" and Old Islandic rǿtask.

Note by the way, that PIE prohibited roots starting with r- altogether, a rule about which Vasmer (and Pokorny) could not know.

Comment: Purely speculative on my part (I don't know the expected transforms from PIE) but the Armenian is word with the same meaning is *uɾɑχ*: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%B8%D6%82%D6%80%D5%A1%D5%AD  (The hy. version also gives no etymology.)